# Do I need equal number of bins for all attributes?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, predictive-modeling, data-cleaning, preprocessing

I want to change 8 attributes which are numeric into nominal. I used equal width binning to specify intervals. Does the bin for each attribute need to be equal? For example, when I discretize attribute A into 3 bins, do the bins of the remaining attributes need to be 3 as well, or not?

Answer (score 0):

If there is no reason specific to your problem to have equal bins, then I'd say no. In fact, binning attributes is often criticized for being "arbitrary". You should not select the number of bins based on some arbitrary rule. Binning usually makes only sense if you expect your response to be a step function. If this is not the case, you should consider carefully how you select your bins and whether binning is appropriate for every variable individually. See [here](http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/wiki/Main/CatContinuous) for a list of potential problems and [this answer on crossvalidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/68839/127417).